# Yolov8 - box_loss and dfl_loss stays at 0. cls_loss converges. Model not giving me bounding box predictions

Tags: object-detection, yolo

I'm having trouble using Yolov8 to work properly. I have my own custom dataset and an online dataset that I am using. Yolov8 trains on these datasets. However, the only metric that converges is the cls_loss.

It seems like the model isn't giving me any sort of bounding boxes to compute box_loss. When I go into the results file, I can see that the model sees the labels and bounding box properly, so I'm not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: Please check bounding box format , Yolo algorithm required bounding box coordinates in  (x, y, width, height) format.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the 'classes' parameter in the yaml file is blank.
classes:
As that parameter will filter out the classes listed there. Meaning if you set classes: [], it will not take in any classes when performing the Non Max Suppression function.